# geemap.zonal_statistics yields error "ImageCollection.toBands: Too many bands (more than 5000)."

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to extract environmental data from Google Earth and using geemap.zonal_statistics to convert into CSV file:

```
#Add ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_RAW dataset
images = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")\
    .select('temperature_2m')\
    .filterDate("2020-01-01","2020-12-31")

features = [
            # Svalbard Geometry
            ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon([[10.493629, 79.839339],
                                            [24.554229, 80.454159],
                                            [27.580726, 80.081150],
                                            [24.428125, 77.466071],
                                            [16.042206, 76.500817],
                                            [10.493629, 79.839339]]), {'name': 'Svalbard'})
            ]


fcoll= ee.FeatureCollection(features)

out_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads')
out_stats = os.path.join(out_dir, 'Svalbard_temp_average.csv')

if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
    os.makedirs(out_dir)

# Allowed output formats: csv, shp, json, kml, kmz
# Allowed statistics type: MEAN, MAXIMUM, MINIMUM, MEDIAN, STD, MIN_MAX, VARIANCE, SUM
geemap.zonal_statistics(images, fcoll, out_stats, statistics_type='MEAN', scale=2000)
```

I got the following error:

```
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py:337, in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    336 try:
--> 337   return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    338 except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:

File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py:130, in positional.<locals>.positional_decorator.<locals>.positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    129         logger.warning(message)
--> 130 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py:938, in HttpRequest.execute(self, http, num_retries)
    937 if resp.status >= 300:
--> 938     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    939 return self.postproc(resp, content)

HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/value:compute?prettyPrint=false&alt=json returned "ImageCollection.toBands: Too many bands (more than 5000).". Details: "ImageCollection.toBands: Too many bands (more than 5000).">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\geemap\common.py:6779, in zonal_stats(in_value_raster, in_zone_vector, out_file_path, statistics_type, scale, crs, tile_scale, return_fc, verbose, timeout, proxies, **kwargs)
   6778     else:
-> 6779         ee_export_vector(result, filename, timeout=timeout, proxies=proxies)
   6780 except Exception as e:

File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\geemap\common.py:1533, in ee_export_vector(ee_object, filename, selectors, verbose, keep_zip, timeout, proxies)
   1532 if selectors is None:
-> 1533     selectors = ee_object.first().propertyNames().getInfo()
   1534     if filetype == "csv":
   1535         # remove .geo coordinate field

File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\ee\computedobject.py:96, in ComputedObject.getInfo(self)
     91 """Fetch and return information about this object.
     92 
     93 Returns:
     94   The object can evaluate to anything.
     95 """
---> 96 return data.computeValue(self)

File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py:916, in computeValue(obj)
    914 _maybe_populate_workload_tag(body)
--> 916 return _execute_cloud_call(
    917     _get_cloud_api_resource().projects().value().compute(
    918         body=body,
    919         project=_get_projects_path(),
    920         prettyPrint=False))['result']

File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py:339, in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    338 except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
--> 339   raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)

EEException: ImageCollection.toBands: Too many bands (more than 5000).

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 9>()
      5     os.makedirs(out_dir)
      7 # Allowed output formats: csv, shp, json, kml, kmz
      8 # Allowed statistics type: MEAN, MAXIMUM, MINIMUM, MEDIAN, STD, MIN_MAX, VARIANCE, SUM
----> 9 geemap.zonal_statistics(images, fcoll, out_stats, statistics_type='MEAN', scale=2000)

File C:\Users\Public\anaconda\envs\terra\lib\site-packages\geemap\common.py:6781, in zonal_stats(in_value_raster, in_zone_vector, out_file_path, statistics_type, scale, crs, tile_scale, return_fc, verbose, timeout, proxies, **kwargs)
   6779         ee_export_vector(result, filename, timeout=timeout, proxies=proxies)
   6780 except Exception as e:
-> 6781     raise Exception(e)

Exception: ImageCollection.toBands: Too many bands (more than 5000).
```

I like to understand what's happening, and how I can go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

it looks, like GEE python API now has a limit to create an image from an imageCollection with function `.toBands()`, to a maximum of 5000 bands. The problem is not geemap but the python API of google earth engine(GEE).

use `.size().getInfo()` to get the number of images and multiply by the number of bands per image, before calling `.toBands()` to make sure you wont go over this new limit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my script. I had written the following code which suddenly gave me the max bands error when trying to do the zonal stats:

```
# Zonal statistics 
temperature_max_image = temperature_max.toBands() 
temperature_min_image = temperature_min.toBands() 
out_temperature_max_stats = os.path.join(png_out_dir, 'temperature_max_zonal_stats.csv')  
out_temperature_min_stats = os.path.join(png_out_dir, 'temperature_min_zonal_stats.csv')  
fp_fig_out = os.path.join(png_out_dir, 'temperature_zonal_stats.png')
geemap.zonal_statistics(temperature_min_image, aoi, out_temperature_min_stats, statistics_type='MEAN')
geemap.zonal_statistics(temperature_max_image, aoi, out_temperature_max_stats, statistics_type='MEAN')
HOTTEST_MONTH, COLDEST_MONTH, TMIN_DAILY_MIN, TMAX_DAILY_MAX = make_temperature_graph(out_temperature_min_stats, out_temperature_max_stats, fp_fig_out)
```

I wrote a workaround which cuts the ImageCollection into multiple chunks and does the zonal_stats for each chunk:

```
def split_image_collection(image_collection, chunk_size=5000):
 ''' Function to split an ImageCollection into chunks'''
    collection_list = image_collection.toList(image_collection.size())
    num_chunks = image_collection.size().divide(chunk_size).ceil()
    chunks = []
    for i in range(0, num_chunks.getInfo()):
        start = i * chunk_size
        end = ee.Number(i + 1).multiply(chunk_size)
        chunk = ee.ImageCollection(collection_list.slice(start, end))
        chunk.toBands()
        chunks.append(chunk)
    return chunks

def zonal_stats_per_chunk(chunks, aoi, out_stats_file, stats_type='MEAN'):
    csv_dir = os.path.dirname(out_stats_file)
    fn = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(out_stats_file))[0]

    df_list = []
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        image = chunk.toBands()
        out_stats_fn = os.path.join(csv_dir, f'{fn}_{i}.csv')
        geemap.zonal_statistics(image, aoi, out_stats_fn, statistics_type=stats_type)
    
        df = pd.read_csv(out_stats_fn)
        df_list.append(df)
    
    merged_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1,)
    merged_df.to_csv(out_stats_file, index=False)
    return

# Split temperature_max and temperature_min into chunks
temperature_max_chunks = split_image_collection(temperature_max)
temperature_min_chunks = split_image_collection(temperature_min)

# Zonal statistics for all chunks
out_temperature_max_stats = os.path.join(png_out_dir, 'temperature_max_zonal_stats.csv')  
out_temperature_min_stats = os.path.join(png_out_dir, 'temperature_min_zonal_stats.csv')  
zonal_stats_per_chunk(temperature_min_chunks, aoi, out_temperature_min_stats, 'MEAN')
zonal_stats_per_chunk(temperature_max_chunks, aoi, out_temperature_max_stats, 'MEAN')
```